# Spring Hibernate schema update not works with minus sign in database name

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and hibernate is set to access the database in the application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/banquets-booking?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
# this not helps as puts in quotes table field name only
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true

#update validate create create-delete
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Now I have added a new field to the entity, but the update fails:

```
2018-09-03 13:05:34.893 TRACE 20867 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory           : Scoping types to session factory org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@56922754
Hibernate: 

    alter table banquets-booking.sub_event 
       add column outlet_id bigint
2018-09-03 13:05:35.841  WARN 20867 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
```

This looks like a bug, because Hibernate was able to generate the schema initially, but fails on the update.

How can I resolve this issue, without renaming the database?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not because of the minus sign.

You should try adding a dialects like one of the below lines.The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

OR

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLMyISAMDialect
```

OR

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
```

to see which one works for you.

Comment: No, seems like this not helps. I added spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect. Also I tried MySQL5Dialect and MySQLInnoDBDialect - nothing works